# caret: combine createResample and groupKFold

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I want to do a custom sampling with `caret`. My specifications are the following:
I have 1 observation per day, and my grouping factor is the month (12 values); so in the first step I create 12 resamples with 11 months in the training (11*30 points) and 1 in the testing (30 points). This way I get 12 resamples in total.

But that's not enough to me and I would like to make it a little more complex, by adding some bootstrapping of the training points of each partition. So, instead of having 11*30 points in Resample01, I would have several bootstrapped resamples of these 330 points. 
So in the end, I want a lot of resamples, but with one of the months NEVER in the training set.

How to specify this in a call to `train`?
What I tried:

```
library(caret)
x = rep(1:12, each=30)
folds = groupKFold(x, k=12)
folds2 = lapply(folds, createResample, times=10)
```

but this is wrong because 1/ i get a nested list, 2/ the initial indices are lost at the second step.
[image]

Thanks for your help (and don't hesitate to tell me if you think it's a XY pb)

Comment: I initially suggested `purrr::map_df(folds, createResample, times = 10, .id = "id")`, but this isn't workable with `caret::trainControl()`

Comment: @Phil thanks for your help anyway, I was glad to discover this `map` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trust this will solve your problem

```
library(caret)
x <- rep(1:12, each = 30)
folds <- groupKFold(x, k = 12)
```

provide 10 bootstrap replicates in a nested list for each of the groups in `folds` -  this solves the lost indexes problem.

```
folds2 <- lapply(folds, function(x) lapply(1:10, function(i) sample(x, size = length(x), replace = TRUE)))
```

convert nested list to a one dimensional list - this solves the nested list problem.

```
folds2 <- unlist(folds2 , recursive = FALSE, use.names = TRUE)
```

does it work?

```
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(360), x = rnorm(360))

lm_formula <- train(
  y ~ ., df,
  method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "boot" , index = folds2)
)
```

looks like it does.

The only issue is perhaps in the intended `indexOut` for each resample, in the example all indexes not present in the fold were used as test. If I understood you would like to test on the held out months and not on all the held out samples. To solve this:

```
folds_out <- lapply(folds, function(x) setdiff(1:360, x))
folds_out <- rep(folds_out, each = 10)
names(folds_out) <- names(folds2)

lm_formula <- train(
  y ~ ., df,
  method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl(method = "boot" , index = folds2, indexOut = folds_out)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @missuse. You're absolutely right, I indeed wanted to have only the 12th month in the test set. Nice use of `setdiff` by the way. If I get it right, there is no built-in function in caret to achieve what I want.

Comment: @agenis Glad to help. I am unsure if there is a built in caret function, from what I know this functionality is not inbuilt, but you might want to check `createTimeSlices` and `trainControl(method = "timeslice"...` To me it looks like they are able to form sets so only prediction on future data is possible, I have never performed serious ts analyses so my knowledge is lacking in this area. Also from what I can see your example does not fall strictly into ts analyses since you would like to predict previous time on later observations too.

Comment: you're right i"m not in the time series framework, and I don"t use timeseries-specific models here.